# Prevent Angular CLI from compiling less files

Tags: angular, less, angular-cli

I am trying to apply a dynamic theme to my site using less variables. Here's a simplified scenario:

File: site.less

```
@primary-color: 'red'
```

File: foobar.component.less

```
@import '../site.less';
.some-element {
    background-color: @primary-color;
}
```

This works just fine for the initial page load and the background color is red. But now I want a drop down color selector with multiple color options. When the user selects green instead of red I want to use the less function [less.modifyVars({'@primary-color', 'green'})](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables), which results in no change. This is because angular cli is pre-compiling the less into css, so the browser never sees the less files to begin with.

So I am thinking if Angular does not compile the less files into css, then the browser will pick up on the changes when modifyVars is called.

How do I tell Angular not to compile less into css?

Comment: You will probably need to use the cli's [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) command and configure webpack to not compile less.

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with that command, would that mean I wouldn't be using Angular CLI for builds anymore, but rather native webpack?

Comment: Correct, it gives you full control over the build

Comment: I will try that and see if I can get it working. In the mean-time, could you submit this as a solution to the question? If I get it working I'll mark it as the accepted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular cli's [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) command. This will eject a webpack configuration file which will give you full control on how the build commands build.

**Side Note:** I don't believe it's impossible to revert `ng eject`, but I've read that it is not always an easy process. Especially when multiple versions have passed with the angular cli team adding/modifying functionality to the build commands.

Comment: I've decided to take a different approach altogether since I've seen multiple sources (including less itself) mention not to compile in browser. But in terms of this question this is the correct answer.

Comment: @heilch yeah, I would definitely recommend a different approach. This gets into the weeds of the build process.

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't change your variable name in less file?

Comment: The CLI compiles the less on the server before it gets to the browser. It replaces all instances of the variable with the hex value directly in the css, which is what gets served to the browser. From the browser's point of view there never was a variable to rename

Comment: On which way you connect your site.less with Angular?

Comment: In the file .angular-cli.json there is a configuration array for "styles", I have included the less file there. The component less file is just picked up during the compile from what I can tell

Comment: Whats about add this file to the index.html file and remove this from angular-cli.json?

Comment: I tried that. It allows me to modify variables in the site.less file, but anything in the foobar.component.less file remains static. I need angular cli to ignore ALL less files and serve them as is